# How to change mpexes under myStoreInitialData/resources (hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# [y] hybris Platform
#
# Copyright (c) 2018 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company.  All rights reserved.
#
# This software is the confidential and proprietary information of SAP
# ("Confidential Information"). You shall not disclose such Confidential
# Information and shall use it only in accordance with the terms of the
# license agreement you entered into with SAP.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ImpEx for Importing Categories

# Macros / Replacement Parameter definitions
$productCatalog=__PRODUCT_CATALOG_NAME__
$productCatalogName=__PRODUCT_CATALOG_FULL_NAME__
```

for example path of this is:

> hybris/bin/custom/myStore/myStoreinitialdata/resources/myStoreinitialdata/import/sampledata/productCatalogs/catalogName/categories_en.impex

but i want to make

```
$productCatalog=__PRODUCT_CATALOG_NAME__
```

to

```
$productCatalog=__myStore_PRODUCT_CATALOG_NAME__
```

There are lots of impexes under initialdata. So, i need something inside code.

Where is the place to do this, `buildcallbacks`?

EDIT

is it ok?

Comment: Yes, you have to write custom target which basically does find and replace job.

Answer (score 2):

You are at the right spot. After you have generate your custom extensions with the following command:

```
ant modulgen accelerator
```

You have to go through your extensions and have to replace those kind of variables. I think the most stuff is in the 'core' and 'initialdata' extension. So you have to look for the following variables and have to change them:

```
__PRODUCT_CATALOG_NAME__ -> MyStoreProductCatalog
__CONTENT_CATALOG_NAME__ -> MyStoreContentCatalog
__SOLR_INDEX_NAME__ -> MyStoreSolrIndex
...
```

You also have to adapt your folder structure for those changes. Have a look into the **InitialDataSystemSetup.java** and **CoreSystemSetup.java** Class. There you will find the method for the logic behind those stuff

Comment: I thought it was not related to java code, maybe it was about xml or ant. This method is from initialdata, can it be the method ``` @SystemSetup(type = Type.PROJECT, process = Process.ALL)
 public void createProjectData(final SystemSetupContext context)
 {
  /*
   * Add import data for each site you have configured
   */```

Comment: yes, this is one methode which will look for impex files with the correct names. Just go step by step through it

Answer (score 0):

I did by editing buildcallbacksxml